# KODi and terminal are not reacting to all buttons from remote control (rc_core)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote

I have bought a NUC5i5RYH, which has an integrated IR-receiver. I've installed Ubuntu 15.04 which comes with rc_core automatically activated.

`ir-keytable -t` works fine and shows ALL keys from my MCE-Remote (I'm using a Logitech Harmony One, configured as MCE).

Only very few keys (e.g. the ENTER-Key) are transferred correctly to a running terminal on desktop or to a `kodi --standalone`.

I have changed a single key to the "Q"-Key to further test this issue, and the custom keymap is recognized:

```
root@arthur:/etc/rc_keymaps# ir-keytable -r
...
scancode 0x800f040a = KEY_Q (0x10)
...
Enabled protocols: RC-6 LIRC
```

And this is working good with `ir-keytable -t`

```
1433079753.108685: event type EV_MSC(0x04): scancode = 0x800f040a
1433079753.108685: event type EV_KEY(0x01) key_down: KEY_Q(0x0001)
1433079753.108685: event type EV_SYN(0x00).
1433079753.232263: event type EV_MSC(0x04): scancode = 0x800f040a
1433079753.232263: event type EV_SYN(0x00).
1433079753.483030: event type EV_KEY(0x01) key_up: KEY_Q(0x0001)
1433079753.483030: event type EV_SYN(0x00).
```

Still, I don't receive a "q" or whatever on the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bitter but simple:

For X to recognize the new key, it must be restarted:

`sudo service lightdm restart`

And afterwards, the KEY_Q worked like a charm.